# Using ng-options for select input

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options, materialize

I am using ng-options for select input.But it is just not populating the drop down list.I am using materialize css  as css framework.

Here is my code

```
<div class="col s6" >
    <select ng-options="bucket.id as bucket.name for bucket in buckets track by bucket.id" ng-model="new_transaction.bucket"></select>
</div>
```

Js Code

```
$scope.new_transaction = {
    "bucket":""
}

$scope.buckets = [
    {
        id:1,
        name:"bucket-1"
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:"bucket-2"
    }
]

$(document).ready(function() {
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
    $('select').material_select();
});
```

Note :There are no errors in the console.
And the inspect element on the dropdown element shows me

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
   <span class="caret">▼</span>
    <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-b1cded87-bee7-c9cd-5564-c613f7439e7a" value="">
    <ul id="select-options-b1cded87-bee7-c9cd-5564-c613f7439e7a" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" style="width: 294px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 1; display: none;">
    </ul>
    <select ng-options="bucket.id as bucket.name for bucket in buckets track by bucket.id" ng-model="new_transaction.bucket_id" class="initialized ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"><option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
 <option label="Bucket-1" value="1">Bucket-1</option>
 <option label="Bucket-2" value="2">Bucket-2</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply

```
$('select').material_select();
```

only when you are ready that ngOptions directive is done.
the simplest and most used solutions is to put plugin init inside $timeout:

```
$timeout(function(){
   $('select').material_select();
})
```

Comment: I dint get you! What do you mean by "plugin init"?

Comment: Using a`$timeout` to apply a jquery plugin in angular is bad practice. It should be a directive.

Comment: and put $timeout inside directive :)

Comment: That's not a proper usage for `$timeout`. It's not needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You've included angular, but you haven't set it up properly to actually use it. You need to create a module, a controller and a directive for what you're trying to accomplish.

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.new_transaction = {
    bucket:""
   };

   $scope.buckets = [
   {
      id:1,
      name:"bucket-1"
   },
   {
      id:2,
      name:"bucket-2"
   }];


}]);

angular.module('app').directive('materialSelect', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem) {
         $(elem).material_select();
      }
   };
});
```

On your body tag, include:

```
<body ng-app="app">
```

On the container of your main content, include:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
   <!-- your other content including the select -->
</div>
```

Then use the `materialSelect` directive as an attribute like this:

```
<select material-select ng-options="bucket.id as bucket.name for bucket in buckets track by bucket.id" ng-model="new_transaction.bucket"></select>
```

Comment: I have done all this,but i haven't put the entire code in the question because it was too big and most of it was irrelevant.But thank you for taking the effort and writing the entire code.

Comment: No errors in console.I have specified the html element output in the question.Please check that.

Comment: From that html, it's showing your drop down is populated. Have you created the `materialSelect` directive like I showed? I think that's your problem. The plugin initializes before the drop down is populated, so it isn't showing any items.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **initialized buckets** before and asynchronous request ng-options will get it empty because ng-options took buckets first time it was modified. For example:

```
$scope.buckets = [];

$http.get('/get buckets/').then(function (result) {
  $scope.buckets = result.data;
});
```

So removing `$scope.buckets = [];` makes ng-options wait until buckets its puplated after callback.